# split pptx to single slides using apache poi

Tags: java, apache, split, apache-poi, powerpoint

I am trying to split pptx slides in to individual slides using apache POI library. I am using POI 3.11. However, it works fine when there are no hyperlinks (viz. links I refer to other slides not not web links). Whenever there is hyperlink, the exact number of slides within the document are not read accurately. Also, the split happens but the number of slides are reduced and they are kind of corrupted as well.

Are there any other tools available? or Is there any better ways of splitting it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you doing the split with Apache POI? Can you show the code you're using?

Comment: I solved it. There seems to be a bug in the source code and I modified it and used the new build on my local. Thanks.